# Why Not working RSA encryption and decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I encoded an RSA decryption and encryption functions, like following:

```
def encrypt(m,e,n):
    return pow(int(m.encode('hex'), 16), int(e, 10), int(n, 10) )


def decrypt(c,d,n):
    p = pow(int(c, 10), int(d, 10), int(n, 10))
    return hex(p)[2:].decode('hex')
```

When I want to use these functions like following, everything is ok

```
e = "65537"
n = "21856687"
d = "12096993"
m = "TH"

c =  encrypt(m,e,n)
print decrypt(str(c),d,n)
```

> But when I change the message to be encrypted (in this case **m**) I
>   get wrong answer, actually they seem like garbage value. What I mean
>   by changing the message is trying a message which has a length longer
>   than 2, like the following.

```
e = "65537"
n = "21856687"
d = "12096993"
m = "THIS IS A HIDDEN MESSAGE"

c =  encrypt(m,e,n)
print decrypt(str(c),d,n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The message bytes, interpreted as a Big Endian number, must be less than `n` for it to roundtrip. You'll need to crank up `p` and `q` or shrink your message. (Your "garbage" is an equivalent message modulo n, it should roundtrip just fine)

And while this is hopefully homework, I feel compelled to state that raw (unpadded) RSA is a bad idea, and DIY RSA is a bad idea. The former is susceptible to a variety of data attacks, and the latter likely has timing vulnerabilities leading to private key compromise.

Comment: I could not handle it could you please help me? I tried to shirnk the message but it did not work

Comment: `n`=21856687 => `0x01 4D 81 AF`.  If `m.encode('hex')` produces a value larger than that your results are unstable.  So if that does an ASCII encoding with no trailing NUL you get 3 characters. If it does UTF-8 you get 3 characters, and if it does UTF-16LE you get 2, or UTF-16BE you get 1.  25-bit RSA doesn't encrypt very much.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right, this what happens when I use ASCII encoding, I get 3 characters. So what I need to do is to divide the message into x parts where x includes max 3 characters, and then concatenate the resulting integer. is that right?

Comment: That would depend on what the particulars of your homework problem were.  RSA is only supposed to be used as a single-block algorithm, and your proposal is to use it as a chained block algorithm, which is frowned upon (for RSA).  The only words of advice I have at this point are "padded hex digits concatenate well, decimal doesn't".

Comment: This does not help me but ,anyway, Thank you very much. Probably I am going to wrong way, because my homework can not be that hard.